# Does Python round matrix elements?

Tags: matrix

I was doing matrix multiplication with a calculator and in python and it seems like small numbers were rounded up to 0 in python is this real or did I make a mistake? Can you somehow override this to get more precision?

Comment: Hello! What is the the number of digits after the decimal point ?

Comment: This is normal result.